# Set British PC Keyboard layout on iPad

Tags: ipad, keyboard, settings, ipados

I use the “British PC” layout on macOS, and I’ve started using a keyboard with my iPad (iOS 13.4.1), and I want to use the same layout on it. However there’s only “British” and “International – PC” neither of which match the British PC layout. Is there a way to change the keyboard layout to match the macOS layout?

Answer (score 2):

I think iOS 14 may have British PC as an option now.

If not, or if you can't upgrade, there’s no way yet to add or customize hardware layouts in iOS, even via an app, as far as I know. You can ask Apple to add this feature via

http://www.apple.com/feedback

Comment: Doesn't seem to be there... At least not in *Settings > Keyboard > Keyboards*....

Comment: @Thinkr  You need to look in settings > general > keyboard > hardware keyboard and tap over at the right edge for English.  You should see a long list of mappings, hopefully including British PC.  A hardware keyboard must be connected.

Comment: Oh, yep, I see it now, thanks!